# Add A Warning For Large Files To My LOCAL Git Repository

Tags: git, git-lfs

I've hit the large file limit for adding files to a Github Enterprise repository, but the problem only presents itself on a "git push".

Is there any way to have my LOCAL Git repository on my client report large files as an error when I try to stage or commit them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with `git-tfs` I'm guessing you're running on Windows?  If so, check out this article on [writing git pre-commit hooks](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-Git-pre-commit-hook/).  This one gives an example of how you can write your pre-commit hook in Powershell.

Of course, this isn't foolproof since you can add a `--no-verify` to your `git commit` to skip the pre-commit hook.